# How to detect swipe on listview?

Tags: android

I have used below code to detect swipe on listview:

SwipeGestureListener.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SwipeGestureListener implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 100;

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;
    protected MotionEvent mLastOnDownEvent = null;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;

    public SwipeGestureListener(Context context) {
    }

    @Override   
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if (e1==null)
            e1 = mLastOnDownEvent;
        if (e1==null || e2==null)
            return false;

        float dX = e2.getX()-e1.getX();
        float dY = e2.getY()-e1.getY();

        if (Math.abs(dY)<SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH && Math.abs(velocityX)>=SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY && Math.abs(dX)>=SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE ) {
            if (dX>0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   @Override
   public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return false;
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

MyActivity.java

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.song_list_listview);

final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(this, new SwipeGestureListener(this));
listview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

});
```

This code works but it seems it only works when I do the swipe gesture on same item of listview.

So for example, I have item 1, 2, and 3. When I start swiping on item 2, the ongoing swiping gesture must be within item 2 layout and end on item 2 layout for the gesture detection to work.

What is the best way to detect swipe on listview? Thanks!